# How do you add margin to a button with a css background image?

Tags: html, css

I have a button with a search icon background image but I am not able to add a `margin-bottom` to align the text area with the button. Why does adding a `margin-bottom` to the button not do anything? Or what is the correct way to align the textarea with the button?

```css
.input-area {
    width: 100%;
    height: 46px;
}

.parse-text-button {
    background: url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hawcons/32/698627-icon-111-search-32.png) no-repeat;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    border: none;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-area">
    <textarea class="input" placeholder="Enter text here"></textarea>
    <button class="parse-text-button" type="submit"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to manually position the second element, I would recommend using `position: relative` in conjunction with a negative `top`. This allows full control over **exactly** where the image sits:

```css
.input-area {
  width: 100%;
  height: 46px;
}

.parse-text-button {
  background: url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hawcons/32/698627-icon-111-search-32.png) no-repeat;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  top: -11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-area">
  <textarea class="input" placeholder="Enter text here"></textarea>
  <button class="parse-text-button" type="submit"></button>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can align the two elements at the top by giving the second element `vertical-align: top`. This aligns the top of the image to the top of the textarea, though can cause problems if the elements are of differing heights (as in your example).

However, considering your image is a little offset from its bounds, you may opt to use this approach to save one line of code:

```css
.input-area {
  width: 100%;
  height: 46px;
}

.parse-text-button {
  background: url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hawcons/32/698627-icon-111-search-32.png) no-repeat;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-area">
  <textarea class="input" placeholder="Enter text here"></textarea>
  <button class="parse-text-button" type="submit"></button>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I found the position: relative to be quiet helpful! I'm not quite sure why but with position relative, if I resize the textarea, the search icon will follow the bottom right corner of the textbox which is quite nice. https://jsfiddle.net/cvczx8st/6/

Answer (score 0):

You can just make both `<textarea>` and the `<button>` *inline-block* so you can use *vertical-align: middle* which will make both elements vertically centered;

```
textarea {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}

.parse-text-button {
   display: inline-block;
   verical-align: middle;
}
```

also make sure to remove all unecessary margin top or bottom in both elements.

hope that helps

Comment: That doesn't seem to work too well here. https://jsfiddle.net/cvczx8st/5/

Comment: @irregular as I have stated you need to make them both `inline-block` and `vertical-align: middle`. I mean both `textarea` and the `button`

Answer (score 0):

There actually is a margin at the bottom, but its extending below the icon and textarea - you can see it if you check it in the element inspector.

I'm guessing that what you really want to know is how to stop the button from being aligned to the bottom.

**You can simply use `vertical-align` to align it, e.g.**

```css
.input-area {
  width: 100%;
  height: 46px;
}

.parse-text-button {
  background: url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hawcons/32/698627-icon-111-search-32.png) no-repeat;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border: none;
  vertical-align: top; /* align to the top */
  margin-top: 4px; /* add a little extra space to the top for 'padding' */
}
```

```html
<div class="input-area">
  <textarea class="input" placeholder="Enter text here"></textarea>
  <button class="parse-text-button" type="submit"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use vertical align

```
.parse-text-button {
    background: 
    url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hawcons/32/698627-icon-111-search-32.png) no-repeat;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    border: none;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

***Here the solution***

```css
.stylish-input-group .input-group-addon{
    background: white !important; 
}
.stylish-input-group .form-control{
 border-right:0; 
 box-shadow:0 0 0; 
 border-color:#ccc;
}
.stylish-input-group button{
    border:0;
    background:transparent;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
            <div id="imaginary_container"> 
                <div class="input-group stylish-input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Search" >
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <button type="submit">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                        </button>  
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
</div>
```